# Generate Android Javadoc with Ant

Tags: java, android, ant, javadoc

I am using the following snippet to generate Javadoc for an Android app:

```
<javadoc
    destdir="bin/docs"
    classpath="${class.path}"
    access="protected" author="true" version="true" use="true"
    failonerror="true">
    <packageset dir="src">
        <include name="com/company/product/**" />
    </packageset>
    <packageset dir="gen">
        <include name="com/company/product/**" />
    </packageset>
</javadoc>
```

This works, but there are lots of warnings from the generated files, e.g. `R.java:1337: warning - @attr is an unknown tag`

The problem is that the generated files are required for Javadoc compilation, if I exclude them I get lots of `error: package R does not exist`.

Now the question is, is there a way to generate error and warning free Javadoc files for Android apps using Ant? Is it possible to *include* the generated files for compilation, but *exclude* them from actual Javadoc generation?